# Run apache as a service from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I have been working on a Java webservice using AXIS and Apache Tomcat. I have deployed it on a Server remotely and I am using eclipse to Run the web server.

When I log off from the machine the web service will be stoped.

I need to keep the web service always running no matter what. Its is better if eclipse could handle this.

I would appreciate a specific answers.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to keep your server running even when you close Eclipse?

Comment: why do you need to run it from eclipse?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan yes even if i close and i log off from the machine

Comment: @buymypies if you have a solution plz go ahead (using eclipse is not mandatory but favorable ).

Comment: @user1912404 I don't think that the server will keep running when you close your eclipse, lets wait from a better answer

Comment: Thing is that if you deploy some code in a server within eclipse you are most likely running an instance on your machine via eclipse and it is therefor not a `remote` server. I don't know your usecase but it seems a discutable idea to run a server from your machine.

Comment: What operating system is this for?